# UISwitch off state is not stable while scrolling in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

I'm creating a UISwitch programmatically in one of the tableview datasource function(cell for row at index). when I'm scrolling the table view, the OFF state switches are malfunctioned(UI) two rounds appeared. Attaching the screenshot of the switch.[image]

Appreciate your help!

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    UILabel *title = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:80];
    UILabel *description = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:81];
    UIView *innerView = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:82];

    innerView.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor colorWithRed:229/255.0f green:229/255.0f blue:229/255.0f alpha:1.0]  CGColor];
    innerView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    NSDictionary *displayDict = scenarioListsArray[indexPath.row];
    title.text =[displayDict objectForKey:@"name"];
    description.text = [displayDict objectForKey:@"description"];    
    UISwitch *myswitch = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.size.width-60, (cell.contentView.frame.size.height/2)-20 , 100, 100)];
    myswitch.onTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:25/255.0f green:122/255.0f blue:66/255.0f alpha:1];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:myswitch];
    myswitch.tag = indexPath.row;
    [myswitch addTarget:self action:@selector(cellButtonClickAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    if ([[displayDict objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"ACTIVE"]) {
        [myswitch setOn:YES animated:YES];

    }
    else
    {
        [myswitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Manage reusability of cell by array your problem will be solved

Comment: @Vinod Radhakrishnan you can also set default value of switch in prepareForReuse method of table cell class.

Comment: I have updated my code. could you please explain? @iPatel

Comment: "if ([[displayDict objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"ACTIVE"])": If the switch status, change, I clearly hop that you update `displayDict`. Also `[cell.contentView addSubview:myswitch];` NO. Avoid that, cells are reused (also it's called twice). Why don't you add it already in your custom cell, and just hide it when you don't want it?

Comment: @Larme that's my mistake, it's actually commented code. I'll correct it here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same issue and fixed with following code before creating switch

```
for(UIView *subView in cell. contentView.subviews){
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UISwitch class]]) {
        [subView removeFromSuperview];

    }
    }
```

Or

```
static NSString *TableIdentifier = @"YourCellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:TableIdentifier];
    //place your all UI elements code here.
  }
```

Comment: this code will remove all labels and images placed in the cell.

Comment: screenshot added.

Comment: exact issue i was faced, check this code, if not works, follow @ipatel comments

Comment: we should set tag for switch and then only we should remove from subview

Comment: this code works for uiswitch. but it removes my all other data(label and images). how can i fix it?

Comment: is your lable, image where you placed

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code, try this will work for you,

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    UILabel *title = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:80];
    UILabel *description = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:81];
    UIView *innerView = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:82];

    innerView.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor colorWithRed:229/255.0f green:229/255.0f blue:229/255.0f alpha:1.0]  CGColor];
    innerView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    NSDictionary *displayDict = scenarioListsArray[indexPath.row];
    title.text =[displayDict objectForKey:@"name"];
    description.text = [displayDict objectForKey:@"description"];    
    UISwitch *myswitch = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+597];
    if(mySwitch == nil){
        myswitch = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.size.width-60,(cell.contentView.frame.size.height/2)-20 , 100, 100)];
       [cell.contentView addSubview:myswitch];
       [myswitch addTarget:self action:@selector(cellButtonClickAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    }
    myswitch.onTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:25/255.0f green:122/255.0f blue:66/255.0f alpha:1];
    myswitch.tag = indexPath.row+597; //597 is extra number added to tag
    if ([[displayDict objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"ACTIVE"]) {
        [myswitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [myswitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }

    return cell;
}
```